# Show divisibility by 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, problem-solving, pythagorean-triples

I was stuck at this question:

> Suppose $a^2+b^2=c^2$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$, and neither $a$ nor $b$ is a multiple of 7. Show that $a^2-b^2$ is a multiple of 7

I tried to write $b^2$ as $c^2-a^2$ then get $a^2-b^2=2a^2-c^2$. But this does not seem to generate the solution.

How to solve problems like this, am I missing some theorems concerning Pythagoras numbers?

Comment: Hint: What are the possible remainders when you divide a square number by $7$? This is like knowing that the squares in decimal can end with $0,1,4,5,6,9$ but not $2,3,7,8$. For more information on the ideas involved research quadratic residues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

If $n\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3;n^2\equiv0,1,4,2\pmod7$

So, $a^2,b^2\equiv1,2,4$

Check for $c^2\pmod7$ when $a^2\not\equiv b^2\pmod7$

But my greater concern is how the problem, specifically $\pmod7$ was conceived!

Answer (score 5):

Using [Euclid's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple), $a=2mn, b=m^2-n^2$

We have $7\nmid2mn(m^2-n^2)$

Now, $(m^2-n^2)^2-(2mn)^2=m^4+n^4-6m^2n^2\equiv m^4+n^4+m^2n^2\pmod7$

But $(m^2-n^2)(m^4+n^4+m^2n^2)=(m^2)^3-(n^2)^3\equiv1-1\pmod7$ using Fermat's Little Theorem as $(m,7)=(n,7)=1$

$\implies7|(m^4+n^4+m^2n^2)$ as $7\nmid(m^2-n^2)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I feel it difficult for myself to devise this method, to be honest. Does Dickson's method cover all the numbers which are of Pythagoras relation?

Comment: Could you share the motivation for this method?

Comment: @Rescy_, This was inspired by the idea of Modular Arithmetic and please  go through the updated link :"generating all primitive triples"  WLOG $(a,b)=1$

Comment: I don’t see where the question says the triple is primitive, so I would expect additional factors on the first line. But I believe they can be omitted from the second line and the rest proceeds as shown.